# python pandas throw parseError

Tags: python, pandas

I need help for using python pandas. I have a `A.txt` which has these data (this is an example)

```
0003343 01901310 8193910 91931
9183131 89102010 7373819 83003
3692429 92920202
```

and `B.txt`

```
424u20u 092u9j 902u39 9293u2
9u193jj 901u39 jdo910 903u98
ue9un88
```

So for `A.txt` I did the following and it does print the dataframe with number of column on top

```
import pandas as pd

fileRead = pd.read_csv("A.txt", delim_whitespace = True, header=None, dtype=object)
print fileRead
```

the result

```
       0        1      2       3
0   0003343 01901310 8193910 91931
1   9183131 89102010 7373819 83003
2   3692429 92920202 NaN     NaN
```

but if I do the same with `B.txt`, it gave me error

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 4 and found 1
```

I don't understand. It should be the same result. What should I do to solve this?
Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: Can you post a link to your second txt file, as your code should've worked, there's another problem here

Comment: what is your pandas version and python version?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5miO1jf9SXecUpDWXVsNkVXczg/view?usp=sharing this is the real second text file. My python version is 2.7 and pandas is 0.20.3

Comment: I think this is a bug, if you remove the last line then it works fine, if you use `read_fwf` then it skips the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
df = pd.read_fwf('test3.txt', header=None, dtype=object)

print (df.head())
         0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8
0  0000000  00915  00517  00916  00517  00916  00517  00915  00517
1  0000010  00915  00518  00915  00518  00915  00517  00915  00517
2  0000020  00915  00518  00915  00517  00915  00516  00915  00517
3  0000030  00915  00517  00915  00517  00915  00517  00915  00517
4  0000040  00915  00517  00916  00517  00915  00517  00915  00517

print (df.tail())
              0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8
262140  03fffc0  00916  00513  00916  00514  00916  00516  00916  00514
262141  03fffd0  00916  00513  00916  00514  00916  00514  00916  00514
262142  03fffe0  00916  00514  00916  00514  00917  00514  00916  00514
262143  03ffff0  00916  00514  00916  00514  00916  00514  00916  00514
262144  0400000    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

EDIT:

As EDchum [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184775/python-pandas-throw-parseerror#comment77338584_45184852) is possible last row is dropped. It seems in `python 3.6.` it silently remove.

Comment: No, there is another problem which is not reproducible with the posted data, the posted code should've worked.

Comment: Can you post code to show this as this works for me so I'm a little sceptical, using `pd.read_clipboard` and using `read_csv` works for me here

Comment: Hmmh,  you are right, error is different `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 4`

Comment: One possibility is some duff version of pandas

Comment: I think this is a bug, if you remove the last line then it works fine, using `read_fwf` silently skips the last line

Comment: @EdChum - interesting, for me last row was not dropped.

Comment: My pandas version is `0.20.2` and I use `pd.read_fwf` with `header=None`

Comment: I use same version under windows. Interesting.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6, what's your python version?

Comment: `python: 3.5.1.final.0`

Comment: very odd this the difference in behaviour

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I got it to work using the answer provided. And I forgot to mention, the second text file which I provided its link there actually is the result from a `.raw` file converted to `.txt` file via `hexdump` while the first text file is not. I think that might be possible reason why this error occur. Anyway again thank you for your suggestion and help.

Answer (score 0):

I find when I insert new records in my csv file using Pandas I sometimes get extras columns added as well albeit only for some of the records. So I had to manually edit the csv file to the correct number of columns, making sure I do not delete rows further down in the file that still have the correct number of columns.
This fixes it, although the real problem is why are the extra columns being added? I do not know the answer to that.